# Faking landscape orientation in Activity when locked in portrait

Tags: android, screen-orientation, orientation-changes

The camera app on Android locks its orientation to portrait, and fakes an orientation change when you turn to landscape. The screen never re-orients itself (you don't see the screen reload or shift at all), but the icons turns to make it seem like it changed the orientation. How are they achieving this?

Let's say I did this. So I'm locked in landscape mode, and I rotate the phone so I'm in portrait (at least that's what it looks like to the user). Now if I have any dialog that pop up on top of this Activity, I'd want them to pop up in portrait orientation. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Would having two sets of elements, half hidden at a time be similar to what you are asking?  When they rotate you just change the hidden (View.GONE) elements to be visible and the visible ones disappear.

Comment: [You could check the source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera)